# How to factory reset a Yxtel G928?

Tags: factory-reset

The information I could find online about how to wipe all user data from a Yxtel G928 was confusing and not easy to find, in [long confusingly written forum threads like this one](http://forum.gsmhosting.com/vbb/f723/yxtel-g928-andriod-hard-reset-done-volcano-1700681/), so I'm writing it up clearly here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Turn the phone off the usual way
2. With it off, hold down the power button, volume down button and home key for around 20 seconds
3. It'll start up and show an icon. Press volume down, then a menu will appear
4. Use the volume keys up/down to highlight `wipe data/factory reset` and then use power button to select it
5. Confirm the same way (volume keys to highlight, power button to select)

Comment: Except for the icon in step 3, this is the normal procedure via recovery menu (see our [factory-reset tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/factory-reset/info)). Does it really only show an icon, and you have to press volume-down to bring up the recovery menu? Then I totally agree that is confusing. No hint at that place that you have to press the vol key?

Comment: That's how it was for me, yes